# Limiting Google Play Games API Calls

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

In my game I use Google Play Game for Achievements and Leaderboards.

I've just noticed (by logging into the Google API Console), that performing a simple action such as displaying a leaderboard, results in 2 API calls.  I would have thought this would be only 1.

I'm simply calling the leaderboard like so:

```
public void displayLeaderBoard(){

    if (getGameHelper().isSignedIn()){

        if (leaderboardIntent==null){
            leaderboardIntent = Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), leaderboardID);
        }           
            startActivityForResult(myLeaderboard, 1);
    }           
}
```

Note it is still 2 API calls even when pressing the leadeboard button a 2nd time (therefore not creating a new 'leaderboardIntent').

Also, when submitting a high score, it uses 3 API calls (one for submitting, then again it calls displayLeaderboard() to show the player her/his new high score.

The thing here is if I then exit back to the app and submit the score again, it uses another 3 API calls.  The documentation states:

> Both the Android and iOS client libraries will know not to send a
>   player's score to the server if your score isn't as good as one you
>   recently submitted.

I know I could simply store a copy of the high score in sharedPreferences and then not submit it if it's not high enough, but I'm not sure about this - what if the device has multiple accounts set up for example.

I would be grateful if someone with more knowledge/experience of the Play Games API could confirm if the number of API calls I'm seeing is correct and how this relates to quote above, or whether there is something more I should be doing in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of calls you are seeing could very well be correct. For many APIs, each request has a "cost" related to it. Which means where a read request to a certain API might cost you 1 call, a write request might cost you 5 (just assuming). Hence, depending on the requests you are making your number of calls are going to differ compared to the number of requests made. For example, try this [tool](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) to calculate Youtube API quota cost. Unfortunately I couldn't find any such tool or documentation for Play Games Services API but I hope this makes my point clear.

For optimizing your code to perform it's best, take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#9_quota_and_rate_limiting) and try to optimize your code to follow Best Practices as much as you can.